# Validating a form with a radio group is not working

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button

I am trying to validate a form that contains some selects and a radio group. If something is left unselected, then a popup will appear. Otherwise, the next screen should be shown. My problem is validating the radio group, where each button has an associated value.

I have looked at many questions about radio groups/buttons where the user is looking to determine if a button has been checked. None of these are working. With the code I currently have, I get a popup even after a radio button has been selected. Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed. Thanks in advance.

```
if($("#radio").is(':checked') && $("#one").val() != "" && $("#two").val() != "" && $("#three").val() != "" && $("#four").val() != "" && $("#five").val() != ""){
    $("#next").show();
}
else
    alert("You muct fill out all fields);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid for checking radio button validation.You should use:

```
if(!$("input[name='name_of_radio_buttons']:checked").val())
       alert('Nothing is checked!');
```

Update:

```
if($("input[name='name_of_radio_buttons']:checked").val() && $("#one").val() != "" && $("#two").val() != "" && $("#three").val() != "" && $("#four").val() != "" && $("#five").val() != ""){
$("#next").show();
}
else
alert("You muct fill out all fields);
```

Comment: all that does is completely bypass the validation of that radio group and the next screen shows, whether or not a button has been selected.

Comment: what is the name of the radio buttons you gave. can you share the html.check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

validate checkbox like this :

if ($('#isAgeSelected :checked').size() > 0)
{

```
$("#txtAge").show();
```

} else {

```
$("#txtAge").hide();
```

}